# Avoid out of bound. Try catch vs condition check

Tags: java, optimization

I have a loop iteration that contains many conditions in this form on various arrays of different size

```
if (a[k]<=x){
     if(al[k+1]==y){
         if(a[k+2]>=x){
         }
     }
}
if (b[k]<=x){
     if(al[k+1]==y){
         if(b[k+2]>=x){
         }
     }
}
```

this because I don't want create separate loop for each array.
Clearly if I loop according the size of bigger array the other array can go out of bound.
To avoid this I have thought to add mutiple check on in each condition eg

```
if (b[k]<=x){
     if(sizeAl<k+1 && al[k+1]==y){
         if(sizeB<k+2 && b[k+2]>=x){
         }
     }
```

Alternatively I could use try catch

What is the better choice in terms of performance?
Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Hovercraft Full of Eels's answer notwithstanding, in general explicit checks are better as Throwables are expensive to create

Comment: Show more code, maybe there are other optimizations possible. Hard to say without the context of understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with performance -- an array index out of bounds should never occur in your code, and if it does, it suggests that the code is broken, and so you should never try to catch it. Instead use unit testing or other testing to try to make your code as bullet-proof as possible.

Comment: the performance is the only parameter that I'm looking for in this situation

Comment: @AndreaF: then I hope to never work with you on a project. But seriously, this is a never occurrence -- you should never catch these things. But with a little searching you would already know that use of exceptions is expensive wrt performance.